# If f(x)>g(x) and g(x) is undefined at a point , can f(x) take a value at that point?

Tags: calculus, functions

If there are two functions f and g such that f(x)>g(x) always holds true.
If g(x) is undefined at some x=a then can f(a) exist?

Comment: If $g(x)$ is undefined at $x=a$ then it is not possible that $f(x)>g(x)$ at $x=a$.

Comment: You’re expected to use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) by now.

Comment: When you say “always holds true,” do you mean for all values of $g(x)$ or for all $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: for all x belongs R

Comment: @WW1 That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If $g(x)$ is undefined at $x=a$ then it is not possible that $f(x)>g(x)$ at $x=a$.

The inequality $b>c$ can only be true if both $b$ and $c$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question to carefully check your definition.  How do you define $f(x) \gt g(x)?$  It could be that you require $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to have the same domain and for all points $x$ in the domain $f(x) \gt g(x)$.  In that case $f(x)$ cannot be defined at $a$ if $g(x)$ is not.  It could be that you require $f(x)$ to be defined at all points $g(x)$ is defined and is greater at all of those.  In that case, $f(x)$ is allowed to be defined at $a$ and there is no restriction on it.  It could be that you just require that $f(x) \gt g(x)$ for all points where they are both defined.  That leads to the silly situation that if $f(x)=-1$ for $x \lt 0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x \gt 0$ then $f(x) \gt g(x)$ and $g(x) \gt f(x)$, violating the antisymmetry we usually expect from $\gt$.  I didn't look up the usual definition because I wanted to show how details can change the answer to your question.